# I'm 25 (years old)

Tags: nouns, adjectives

When you say "I'm 25" to mean that you're 25 years old, would you consider "25" a noun or an adjective?

Comment: Try to replace it with another noun and see where it gets you.

Comment: Various nouns _and_ adjectives would make sense here.

Comment: @Edwin: please do name a noun. Just one. I'm curious.

Comment: @RD: I'm specifically asking about a number '25' here. And how can replacing '25' with another noun would get me anywhere?? Could you be more illustrative?

Comment: @user: if something functions as a noun, it can be replaced with another noun. For example, in the previous sentence, if you think "functions" is a noun, you should be able to replace it with, say, "children" and have the result still be grammatical. But you can't, thus it's not a noun. You can replace it with a verb, though. Thus it functions as a verb.

Comment: @Reg: I'm Edwin! (Note that user27275 begins, 'When you say "I'm 25" '.)

Comment: @Edwin so you think 25 is a proper noun there? (I will admit I didn't think of proper nouns.)

Comment: The words goalposts (or should that be Goalposts?) and moving spring swiftly to mind. However: "I'm treasurer for the chess club." ... "You're the club's secretary, did you say?" ... "I'm _treasurer_." And, off the web:  "I'm matron-of-honor". I admit I wouldn't label these as totally generic usages, but you didn't qualify _noun_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: does "I'm car" work? How about "I'm hungry"? Or "I'm quietly". Numbers are weird.

Comment: Some would say the sentence uses *ellipsis* (leaves out the words “years old”, understood from context. Others would say that *25* is a pronoun which stands for “25 years old”.

Comment: @Mitch: "I'm here" is perhaps the one that causes the greatest problems for traditional analytical approaches. I'm beginning to agree with John Lawler that it's mad trying to classify every word (he'd probably say _any_ word). If pressed, I'd have to have _here_ in a locative particle class - it is referring to 'I' rather than in any meaningful way modifying be; like determiners, does not express attributes of the thing referred to; but unlike determiners, does not express the reference of 'I' in the same way say 'the', 'this', 'my', 'many / seven' (see below) do.

Comment: @EA: In "I'm here", do you see "am" as a linking verb? And how about "Here I am."?

Comment: In the well-known expression 'I am', the Speaker (or rather a later translator) is using the existential form of _be_ - a main verb usage. _I exist_. Some have postulated a similar usage in expressions such as _I am here_. The AHDEL says that the following usage of _be_ is non-copular, but Collins says it is copular:

The food is on the table. / John is at the office.

I go with Collins here. I think some languages would miss out the verb and just say something like "I here" - the verb is a necessary linker in English but with little semantic weight. And _here_ is hardly 'modifying' be!

Comment: I agree with you on "I'm here" being a copular clause. Normally, "am" is not stressed. On the other hand, I think a different analysis is in order for "Here I am.", where you always stress "am" since "am" in this particular instance has an existential meaning. What do you think?

Comment: No - I still consider it to be a virtually delexical usage. Classical delexical verbs are, of course, transitive, as in _he took a walk_. They're there because a verb of some sort is required, but are semantically virtually empty. _Here I am_ would rarely be used without some prior discourse or an awareness of the audience's anticipation of / concern for the speaker's arrival (say he was 15 minutes late). Thus we could have: "Is Flywheel in the meeting?" - "Here I am." I don't think the terminal stress is used to highlight am as much as the whole - here is stressed too, and "Here!" works.

Comment: Wouldn't it be an adjective because 'I am 25 years old' is the full sentence. 'I am 25' could mean that you are number 25 in a lineup or number 25 on a soccer team, but it is clearly inferred as 'I am 25 years old' which makes it an adjective to describe a number of years.

Answer (score 4):

Neither. *Twenty-five* is a [numeral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_%28linguistics%29). In your example sentence,  25's syntactic role is that of [a predicative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicative_expression).

Comment: So a number is not a noun?

Comment: @user27275: According to the classification of words into parts of speech that I'm aware of, no

Comment: And something other than a noun or an adjective can be a predicative?

Comment: @user27275: Apparently, yes

Comment: _Predicate_ (and _predicative_) are logical terms; _noun, adjective, verb, numeral_ are grammatical terms. Grammar has its own requirements, but a clause has to have a predicate, and the predicate may well be of almost any meaningful grammatical class. In English, anyway, word class isn't a very trustworthy guide to anything useful -- most words belong to several classes.

Comment: @John Lawler: Not a 'very trustworthy guide' (hence all the related questions that arise), but considered by many (go on, I'll risk most) people to be a very useful analytical tool. Though we do all seem to have different makes.

Comment: Yup. Probably true. And plenty of people don't believe in evolution. Doesn't have any effect on either language or nature.

Comment: This question keeps intriguing me. We say "I'm 25"; "I'm 5 foot 11"; "I'm 11 stone 6" (well, you might); but not "I'm 97 degrees".

Answer (score 3):

I wish Wikipedia would get their act together.

As well as claiming that numerals form a word class (in Armen's link) they claim that numerals form a subset of the determiner word class ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner ):

A determiner is a word, phrase or affix that occurs together with a noun or noun phrase and serves to express the reference of that noun or noun phrase in the context. That is, a determiner may indicate whether the noun is referring to a definite or indefinite element of a class, to a closer or more distant element, to an element belonging to a specified person or thing, **to a particular number or quantity**, etc. Common kinds of determiners include definite and indefinite articles (like the English the and a[n]), demonstratives (like this and that), possessive determiners (like my and their), and quantifiers (like many, few and several).
Most determiners have been traditionally classed along with adjectives, and this still occurs: for example, demonstrative and possessive determiners are sometimes described as demonstrative adjectives and possessive adjectives respectively. However, modern theorists of grammar prefer to distinguish determiners as a separate word class from adjectives, which are simple modifiers of nouns, expressing attributes of the thing referred to. ...

Types of determiners

Articles
Demonstratives
Possessives
Quantifiers
**Numerals**
Distributives

[bolding mine]

Comment: Wikipedia, by definition, can't get its act together. As long as there are different opinions about grammar, they will be used to warp different chunks of Wikipedia in one direction or another.

Comment: Which is worse than boldly splitting to-infinitives.